# How to write a cgi script in perl that accepts output (an image file) from a urlconnection in a Java applet and writes it to the server?

Tags: java, image, perl, cgi

I created a Java applet for my web page that creates an image file. I want users to be able to run the applet and create unique images, click a button, and have the image they created be saved to the web server.

I think I have the code down for writing the image to a URLconnection in the Java applet itself after having successfully written a file while running the applet on my system rather than the web page and saving a file to the local disk, and then altering a few things to write to a URLConnection instead of to the local disk (although we shall see how that works too).

I am now trying to write a cgi script in perl that takes the image output from the URLConnection and writes the image to a file on my web server (note: I am a newbie to perl). I have found many examples of how to do something similar with simple text coming from an applet and then writing it to a text file, but I want to know how to apply the same concept to an image. Particularly, how do I read in the image? I've seen text input get read by using read(STDIN, $some_variable)--does the same thing work with an image? Likewise, how do I write the image file? What function do I use?

Thanks for your help. I know that I am rather naive about all of this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem at server side if you use the [CGI module](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/CGI.pm-3.59/lib/CGI.pm) (see the "PROCESSING A FILE UPLOAD FIELD" section), which can help you. 
And it's important to adapt your applet in order to send the file as if you were using a HTML form with an input type file (so you need to use the POST verb in HTTP protocol, and encode properly the request). [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) may helps.